# DatabaseInitializer doesn't run on when inheriting DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, dbcontext

I'm trying to create a general DbContext that I can use on all my projects and I want that it will create and seed some tables.  So I've tried using a DbInitializer but it only seems to work when creating the parent context.  If I create another context that inherits from it, the parent never gets seeded/initialized.

Is this even the right pattern to use?

```
public class TestParentContext : DbContext
{
    static TestParentContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TestParentContext>(new TestInitializer());
    }
}

public class TestChildContext : TestParentContext
{
    static TestChildContext()
    {
        //no initializer
    }
}

public class TestInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<TestParentContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(TestParentContext context)
    {
        //this only gets run when calling Database.Initialize when used on a TestParentContext
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

//this will not throw the exception
using (TestChildContext ctx = new TestChildContext())
    ctx.Database.Initialize(true);

//this will throw the exception (as I want it to)
using (TestParentContext ctx = new TestParentContext())
    ctx.Database.Initialize(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `web.config` find the entity framework group and change/add the context accordingly

```
<entityFramework>
  <contexts>
    <context type="<libName>.<Context Name>, <Lib Name>">
      <databaseInitializer type="<Lib Name>.<Context Config>, <Lib Name>" />
    </context>
  </contexts>
....
```

Probably the `<ContextName>` is `TestChildContext` and `<Context Config>` is `TestInitializer` you should have one already for `TestParentContext` do not remove/change it.